# Can my oracle still be used by end user when a crontab job update the database?

Tags: database, oracle

I have a crontab job run at 00:00 to update my website database every night;

To prevent the job from brreaking end user's operation on website, should I stop my website during the job is running? Is there any better alternate course? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oracle, like other DBMSs, allows concurrent access to the data, even in case of concurrent readings and writings.

So yes, the users will still be able to access the database during the update job. Depending on what the update job might do and its duration, there might be interferences, but I don't know the details.

Normally, you should try to define the update job in such a way to make sure that there are no interferences with user activities, if possible, instead of shutting down the site while updating.

Answer (score 0):

Try it and if you find you do have interference and the job is very long running check whether the design allows you to COMMIT more often. Otherwise let us know details such as: what the job is doing, how many rows you are likely to insert or update, and which version of Oracle.